# How to send custom error message from azure function to iot device via azure device provisioning service?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am using custom allocation policy in device provisioning service (DPS) to register my iot device to iot hub, in which I am triggering azure function for the same.

Now if my function logic fails, I have to send the custom error message to a device, how would I do that? I know that we can send custom HTTP status code to the device in case of failure but I have to send some custom message along with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this is on the radar of the Azure Device Provisioning Service. Please look for an update over the next two months.

Comment: Thanks for answering, we'll eagerly waiting for it.

Comment: We just announced support for this feature [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-iot-hub-device-provisioning-service-june-2019-update/).

Just include a property called  'payload' in the response body with a JSON object as its value containing the error message.

`{
  "payload" : {
      "errorMessage" : "Encountered error xyz" 
   }
}`